# Detect if someone is server muted by Discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need the bot to detect who is server muted in the server and output it into a text channel

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.voice_states = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('logged as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
  channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name='sprava-serveru')
  print(before)
  print(after)

client.run([TOKEN])
```

The *on_voice_state_update* returns just the *self_mute* and *self_deaf* property, not *mute* or *deaf*. I thought the intents would fix this but I couldn't figure out how. I tried both *discord.Intents.all()* and *discord.Intents.default()* but nothing worked for me.

The output of *print(before)* and *print(after)*:

```
<VoiceState self_mute=False self_deaf=False self_stream=False suppress=False requested_to_speak_at=None channel=<VoiceChannel id=834407963245936661 name='Senát' rtc_region=None position=3 bitrate=64000 user_limit=0 category_id=834407913190850610>>
<VoiceState self_mute=False self_deaf=False self_stream=False suppress=False requested_to_speak_at=None channel=<VoiceChannel id=834407963245936661 name='Senát' rtc_region=None position=3 bitrate=64000 user_limit=0 category_id=834407913190850610>>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you don't see the `deaf` or `mute` attribute when printing the `VoiceState` object, if you take a look at the docs it clearly has the attributes you're looking for: [`VoiceState.deaf`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_voice_state#discord.VoiceState.deaf), [`VoiceState.mute`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_voice_state#discord.VoiceState.mute)